# Regular expression for required format

Tags: regex

What will be the best regular expression if I want to intake alphanumerics, '-' and '+' signs.
e.g. LA2+4 or td1-23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No magic involved, just specify that your complete string (`^...$`) must match a sequence of arbitrary length (`...*`) of alternatively (`[...]`) upper-case letters (`A-Z`), lower-case letters (`a-z`), digits (`0-9`), the plus sign (`+`) and the minus sign (`-`).

The only special case to consider is the fact that the minus sign you want to accept (`-`) must appear as the last (or first) letter in the option group, since the same character is also used to specify ranges (as in `A-Z`).

So, the solution is:

```
    ^[A-Za-z0-9+-]*$
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [A-Za-z0-9-+]

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to parse any numerical representation?
Or just a few? In Perl (your language not given)
you could just use:

```
use Scalar::Util qw( looks_like_number )

my $stuff = get_weird_input();
...

if( looks_like_number($stuff) ) {
  convert( ... )
}
...
```